# How to find a mosquito in a room that's really good at hiding

Tags: home, pest-control

I've been trying to kill a certain mosquito in my room for a week now. I always fail to find it. I used every method listed on this and some other websites. Nothing helped.

Now my plan is the following. I'll fill up a cup with water and leave it be. The idea is that she needs steady water to leave eggs right? so she'll go there to put some eggs. And then I'll kill it.

The problem is she wakes up at night so she might just put eggs and leave and i'll just find a cup with mosquito eggs in it.

Do you think the idea will work?
have got some better ideas or improvements?

Edit:
I see someone does not know how to read properly so I'll repeat.   "I used every method listed on this and some other websites. Nothing helped." So this is in no way a duplicate since that answers did not solve my problem.
If you simply can not answer just leave and do not falsely accuse me.

Comment: @IrakliKoberidze Rude and offensive comments are not allowed here.

Comment: We don't want to split this information by asking the same question again. Even though you didn't find an answer there that suited you, that isn't a good reason to ask the same question again. Hopefully, there will be more answers posted there, but we don't want to split this information between two threads, and much of what has been posted there will simply be reposted here again.

Comment: There's no use in reposting answers from there since they did not help... That's the whole point

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of fly paper. It's cheap and any small insects that land on it are immediately stuck and die. However, I don't guarantee that your mosquito will be attracted to it. It is worth a shot though! Hardware stores, garden stores, and even the big supermarket near my house sell them.